# Office 365 and Active Directory limitations

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-office-365

We are currently using **Office 365 for education** in one of our forest which contains a AD, master of the domain (example.com), a AD "sub-domain" (test.example.com), another AD (examplebis.com) and a DirSyn which works perfectly.

My point here is about the limitation of **50.000 objects** that can be supported by O365. I understand that is for the entire forest, no problem with that.

But I've been asked: "**Is it also concern the deleted objects ?**". I mean here: if i create then delete a user in my O365 account, do I have 50.000 accounts left or 49.999 ?

I've not found an explicit answer in documentation, and even if my question could seem stupid, I prefer asking than giving a uncertain answer.

Comment: You need to [contact the Office 365 support team](https://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-enterprises/hh852534.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I posted my question in http://community.office365.com.

And here is the answer I had back from [Jesper Stähle](http://community.office365.com/en-us/members/jesper-stahle/default.aspx), thanks to him:

> "Hi,
>
> The limitation is about AD-objects. Short answer to the question you have been asked is:
>
> "No."
>
> The limitation is not regarding users in the tenant (enabled or
>   disabled), it regards objects in the on-prem Active Directory (Groups,
>   Contacts, users combined). To be able to syncrhonize deletions,
>   deleted user accounts in AD also Counts.
>
> If you are close to 50K in local AD - I suggest you raise a support
>   ticket stating that you might have more than 50000 AD objects that
>   will be synchronized so that Online Services team can prepare your
>   tenant for this. Also, you should make sure that DirSync is deployed
>   with a full SQL installation for the configuration:
>   technet.microsoft.com/.../jj159544
>
> Also, if you have not already runned the Deployment Readiness Tool, I
>   suggest you do so and analyze the outcome from that:
>   community.office365.com/.../8155.aspx
>
> Best regards,
>
> Jesper Ståhle"